# Cucumber with JUnit 5 per scenario Test Context on parallel execution

Tags: java, spring, junit, cucumber, cucumber-java

Just recently I got to experience scenario parallel execution with Cucumber + JUnit 5 which works fine and I intend to use from now on. Previously since I also use *cucumber-spring*, I've use Spring to manage a single TestContext instance as a bean annotated with `@Component` which I reset every Scenario using `@Before`. Now that there are more scenarios running in parallel, naturally I need a threaded solution. My idea for a solution was roughly the following:

```
/* Store the Current Scenario in a Thread Local */

private ThreadLocal<Scenario> currentScenario = new ThreadLocal<>();

@Before
public void setup(final Scenario scenario) {
  currentScenario.set(scenario);
}
```

```
/* Get Scenario from a Context Map with ScenarioId as the key */

private Map<String, TestContext> contextMap = new HashMap<>();

public TestContext getContext(final Scenario scenario) {
  return contextMap.get(scenario.getId());
}
```

The thing is, I don't know if the Scenario starts and end in a single thread or if this proposed solution is safe at all. Is there any other way to get access to the current Scenario's `Scenario` instance? Any other solutions for this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a recent version of Cucumber, then your step definitions classes are scenario scoped by default and should not be annotated with `@Component`.

Each scenario gets a new instance of the step definition class.

So this is safe, even with parallel execution:

```java
private Scenario currentScenario;

@Before
public void setup(final Scenario scenario) {
  currentScenario = scenario;
}
```

If you have other classes without step definitions that should have a unique instance in each scenario you can combine `@Component` with `@ScenarioScoped`.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-spring#sharing-state-between-steps